# Gedit not found on launchbar when I minimize, Ubuntu 12.10.

Tags: launcher, gedit, minimize

I updated from 12.04 to 12.10, and when I minimize gedit, it doesn't show up in the launch bar. The only way I'm able to get it back is to open one of the files that has already been opened in gedit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it's not exactly what you want, but you can right-click on Gedit's launcher icon and choose ***Lock to Launcher***. Now Gedit will remain there no matter if you currently use it or not.